# How to add/change names of components to an existing Tensorflow Dataset object?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

From the Tensorflow dataset guide it says

> It is often convenient to give names to each component of an element,
>   for example if they represent different features of a training
>   example. In addition to tuples, you can use collections.namedtuple or
>   a dictionary mapping strings to tensors to represent a single element
>   of a Dataset.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
   {"a": tf.random_uniform([4]),
    "b": tf.random_uniform([4, 100], maxval=100, dtype=tf.int32)})
print(dataset.output_types)  # ==> "{'a': tf.float32, 'b': tf.int32}"
print(dataset.output_shapes)  # ==> "{'a': (), 'b': (100,)}"
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets

And this is very useful in Keras. If you pass a dataset object to `model.fit`, the names of the components can be used to match the inputs of your Keras model. Example:

```
image_input = keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3), name='img_input')
timeseries_input = keras.Input(shape=(None, 10), name='ts_input')

x1 = layers.Conv2D(3, 3)(image_input)
x1 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x1)

x2 = layers.Conv1D(3, 3)(timeseries_input)
x2 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x2)

x = layers.concatenate([x1, x2])

score_output = layers.Dense(1, name='score_output')(x)
class_output = layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='class_output')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[image_input, timeseries_input],
                    outputs=[score_output, class_output])

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    ({'img_input': img_data, 'ts_input': ts_data},
     {'score_output': score_targets, 'class_output': class_targets}))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=3)
```

So it would be useful for look up, add, and change names to components in tf dataset objects. What is the best way to go about doing these tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the accepted answer is good for changing names of (existing)components, it does not talk about 'addition'. This can be done as follows:

y_dataset = x_dataset.map(fn1)

where you can define fn1 as you want

```
@tf.function
def fn1(x):
    ##use x to derive additional columns u want. Set the shape as well
    y = {}
    y.update(x)
    y['new1'] = new1
    y['new2'] = new2
    return y
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `map` to bring modifications to your dataset, if that is what you are looking for. For example, to transform a plain `tuple` output to a `dict` with meaningful names,

```
import tensorflow as tf

# dummy example
ds_ori = tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf.data.Dataset.range(0, 10), tf.data.Dataset.range(10, 20)))
ds_renamed = ds_ori.map(lambda x, y: {'input': x, 'output': y})

batch_ori = ds_ori.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
batch_renamed = ds_renamed.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(batch_ori))
  print(sess.run(batch_renamed))
  # (0, 10)
  # {'input': 0, 'output': 10}
```

Comment: If using `padded_batch`, make sure to apply before the renaming, otherwise there will be an error. May also apply to `batch` as well.